# Conditional Logit in a Panel Data setting with varying alternatives over waves

Tags: logistic, panel-data, clogit, choice-modeling

I am working on a panel data setting and this data is on cigarette smoking behavior of individuals.

I am specifically focusing on two variables - the brand name of the cigarette that the individual is smoking and the price paid per stick of cigarette of the brand that the user has purchased. These two variables are present over two waves - 1 and 2. i have created this final data set from the master data set after eliminating missing values, etc.

Now, I have been successful in shaping the data into a long form for the actual logistic regression. I am running a conditional logit on the brand name with respect to the price that is being paid for that brand. Now, if the idea was to estimate the results on each wave individually, there would be no problems and the exercise would already be done. However, I need to study interaction effects and I hence need to combine the data for the two waves. This is where the problem starts. In terms of purchases made by the individuals in wave 1, there were 11 unique brands - by this I mean there were a total of 11 brands which were in the product set. Therefore, I have 11 alternatives at this stage. In wave 2, two of the brands from this set of 11 is missing. Therefore, including the outside option of quitting smoking - which I have coded in the data as 0 for both brand name and price, the total number of alternatives I have in wave 2 are 10. While making the long form of the data, I pushed the outside option in wave 1 as well. Therefore, in total, 12 choices in wave 1 (nobody can choose the outside option in wave 1 - because by definition they are all smokers in wave 1) and 9 options in wave 2 including the outside option (unlike wave 1, some people do choose the outside option in wave 2, because they quit smoking.

The interaction effects that I allude to are to see the effect of an exogenous shock which took place in the market between the two waves. Hence I need to combine the two waves in order to perform the exercise.

Therefore, in this situation, where I have a differing number of choices across the two waves, what is the appropriate course of action? Should I delete the the individuals in wave 1 who are smoking varieties which do not exist in wave 2?

Thanks a lot for your help!

NOTE: 608 observations in total - from where the long format for conditional logit is being created. Furthermore, I am open to performing the analysis on both stata and R.